# Counting a sum with great numbers of summands

Tags: algorithm, binary, sum, dynamic-programming

There's a task to count a sum, summands which is numbers with an [even number of ones in bin](https://oeis.org/A001969) and each number raised to the power of 4. The problem is that the last summand is 2<sup>64</sup>, so the usual calculation takes a long time.
I think dynamic programming can help here, but i can't realize how to use it here.
Here's an example:

[image]

Please, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Every second number has an even number of bits, so there will be around 2^63=9223372036854775808 such numbers. If you plan to iterate through them all, dynamic programming won't help you. I think you'll have to find some cleaver mathematical relation between the numbers and simplify the problem before starting to write "for"-loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [formula to calculate the sum of the powers of 4 of all integers from 1 to n](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html):

sum(k<sup>4</sup>) <sub>for 1<=k<=n</sub> = (6*n<sup>5</sup> + 15*n<sup>4</sup> + 10*n<sup>3</sup> - n) / 30

In your problem you need to sum up only powers of 4 of k's that have an even number of ones in their binary representation. And this formula doesn't exclude k's with odd number of ones.

However, my gut feeling tells me that the sum of powers of 4 of k's that have an odd number of ones should be about the same as the sum of powers of 4 of k's with an even number of ones.

It turns out that if you calculate these two sums for a range of k's, these sums will be exactly the same once in a while, once in every 32 k's:

```
n=   0 OddSum=                   0 EvenSum=                   0 = =
n=   1 OddSum=                   1 EvenSum=                   0  
n=   2 OddSum=                  17 EvenSum=                   0  
n=   3 OddSum=                  17 EvenSum=                  81  
n=   4 OddSum=                 273 EvenSum=                  81  
n=   5 OddSum=                 273 EvenSum=                 706  
n=   6 OddSum=                 273 EvenSum=                2002  
n=   7 OddSum=                2674 EvenSum=                2002  
n=   8 OddSum=                6770 EvenSum=                2002  
n=   9 OddSum=                6770 EvenSum=                8563  
n=  10 OddSum=                6770 EvenSum=               18563  
n=  11 OddSum=               21411 EvenSum=               18563  
n=  12 OddSum=               21411 EvenSum=               39299  
n=  13 OddSum=               49972 EvenSum=               39299  
n=  14 OddSum=               88388 EvenSum=               39299  
n=  15 OddSum=               88388 EvenSum=               89924  
n=  16 OddSum=              153924 EvenSum=               89924  
n=  17 OddSum=              153924 EvenSum=              173445  
n=  18 OddSum=              153924 EvenSum=              278421  
n=  19 OddSum=              284245 EvenSum=              278421  
n=  20 OddSum=              284245 EvenSum=              438421  
n=  21 OddSum=              478726 EvenSum=              438421  
n=  22 OddSum=              712982 EvenSum=              438421  
n=  23 OddSum=              712982 EvenSum=              718262  
n=  24 OddSum=              712982 EvenSum=             1050038  
n=  25 OddSum=             1103607 EvenSum=             1050038  
n=  26 OddSum=             1560583 EvenSum=             1050038  
n=  27 OddSum=             1560583 EvenSum=             1581479  
n=  28 OddSum=             2175239 EvenSum=             1581479  
n=  29 OddSum=             2175239 EvenSum=             2288760  
n=  30 OddSum=             2175239 EvenSum=             3098760  
n=  31 OddSum=             3098760 EvenSum=             3098760 = =
n=  32 OddSum=             4147336 EvenSum=             3098760  
n=  33 OddSum=             4147336 EvenSum=             4284681  
n=  34 OddSum=             4147336 EvenSum=             5621017  
n=  35 OddSum=             5647961 EvenSum=             5621017  
n=  36 OddSum=             5647961 EvenSum=             7300633  
n=  37 OddSum=             7522122 EvenSum=             7300633  
n=  38 OddSum=             9607258 EvenSum=             7300633  
n=  39 OddSum=             9607258 EvenSum=             9614074  
n=  40 OddSum=             9607258 EvenSum=            12174074  
n=  41 OddSum=            12433019 EvenSum=            12174074  
n=  42 OddSum=            15544715 EvenSum=            12174074  
n=  43 OddSum=            15544715 EvenSum=            15592875  
n=  44 OddSum=            19292811 EvenSum=            15592875  
n=  45 OddSum=            19292811 EvenSum=            19693500  
n=  46 OddSum=            19292811 EvenSum=            24170956  
n=  47 OddSum=            24172492 EvenSum=            24170956  
n=  48 OddSum=            24172492 EvenSum=            29479372  
n=  49 OddSum=            29937293 EvenSum=            29479372  
n=  50 OddSum=            36187293 EvenSum=            29479372  
n=  51 OddSum=            36187293 EvenSum=            36244573  
n=  52 OddSum=            43498909 EvenSum=            36244573  
n=  53 OddSum=            43498909 EvenSum=            44135054  
n=  54 OddSum=            43498909 EvenSum=            52638110  
n=  55 OddSum=            52649534 EvenSum=            52638110  
n=  56 OddSum=            62484030 EvenSum=            52638110  
n=  57 OddSum=            62484030 EvenSum=            63194111  
n=  58 OddSum=            62484030 EvenSum=            74510607  
n=  59 OddSum=            74601391 EvenSum=            74510607  
n=  60 OddSum=            74601391 EvenSum=            87470607  
n=  61 OddSum=            88447232 EvenSum=            87470607  
n=  62 OddSum=           103223568 EvenSum=            87470607  
n=  63 OddSum=           103223568 EvenSum=           103223568 = =
n=  64 OddSum=           120000784 EvenSum=           103223568  
...
n=4062 OddSum=  110517674755433207 EvenSum=  110790187795938168  
n=4063 OddSum=  110790187795938168 EvenSum=  110790187795938168 = =
n=4064 OddSum=  111062969223019384 EvenSum=  110790187795938168  
n=4065 OddSum=  111062969223019384 EvenSum=  111063237807788793  
n=4066 OddSum=  111062969223019384 EvenSum=  111336556602699529  
n=4067 OddSum=  111336556999378505 EvenSum=  111336556602699529  
n=4068 OddSum=  111336556999378505 EvenSum=  111610413558992905  
n=4069 OddSum=  111610683334189626 EvenSum=  111610413558992905  
n=4070 OddSum=  111885079246199626 EvenSum=  111610413558992905  
n=4071 OddSum=  111885079246199626 EvenSum=  111885079246980586  
n=4072 OddSum=  111885079246199626 EvenSum=  112160014909822442  
n=4073 OddSum=  112160285082869867 EvenSum=  112160014909822442  
n=4074 OddSum=  112435761292440443 EvenSum=  112160014909822442  
n=4075 OddSum=  112435761292440443 EvenSum=  112435761691463067  
n=4076 OddSum=  112711778845418619 EvenSum=  112435761691463067  
n=4077 OddSum=  112711778845418619 EvenSum=  112712050215144108  
n=4078 OddSum=  112711778845418619 EvenSum=  112988609908991164  
n=4079 OddSum=  112988609908992700 EvenSum=  112988609908991164  
n=4080 OddSum=  112988609908992700 EvenSum=  113265712541951164  
n=4081 OddSum=  113265984311095421 EvenSum=  113265712541951164  
n=4082 OddSum=  113543630682195597 EvenSum=  113265712541951164  
n=4083 OddSum=  113543630682195597 EvenSum=  113543631082001485  
n=4084 OddSum=  113821821591246733 EvenSum=  113543631082001485  
n=4085 OddSum=  113821821591246733 EvenSum=  113822094560202110  
n=4086 OddSum=  113821821591246733 EvenSum=  114100830807798926  
n=4087 OddSum=  114100830808584494 EvenSum=  114100830807798926  
n=4088 OddSum=  114380113196106030 EvenSum=  114100830807798926  
n=4089 OddSum=  114380113196106030 EvenSum=  114380386566045167  
n=4090 OddSum=  114380113196106030 EvenSum=  114660215895655167  
n=4091 OddSum=  114660216297816991 EvenSum=  114660215895655167  
n=4092 OddSum=  114660216297816991 EvenSum=  114940592970302463  
n=4093 OddSum=  114940867546334192 EvenSum=  114940592970302463  
n=4094 OddSum=  115221793169753088 EvenSum=  114940592970302463  
n=4095 OddSum=  115221793169753088 EvenSum=  115221793169753088 = =
...
```

Without a formal proof I propose that the answer therefore is:

((6*n<sup>5</sup> + 15*n<sup>4</sup> + 10*n<sup>3</sup> - n) / 30) / 2

where n=2<sup>64</sup>-1.

Comment: If I've understood this correctly 'n' denotes the number of bits ?  So for each row in your table the odd sum is the sum of fourth powers of all n-bit numbers with odd parity; and the even sum that for n-bit numbers with even parity ?  If my understanding is correct the first mistake in the table is at n=2 where the even sum should be 81 (11 binary == 3 decimal, 3^4=81).  The table is also wrong in a number of other places where the even sum for 3 consecutive values of n is the same (eg n=24,25,26). If I've misunderstood, please clarify.  Other than this issue, I like the answer.

Comment: `n` is the maximum number we raise to the power of 4 in the sum. In the problem statement it goes from 0 to 3 to 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, ..., 2^64-1. Do the sums of powers of 4 of numbers with odd and even number of ones by hand for small numbers to see what's in the table. My table replicates exactly the sums of powers of 4 of numbers with even number of ones. The "dups" are there because the next `n` contributes either to the "odd" sum or to the "even" sum, but not both since `n` cannot have an even and an odd number of ones at the same time.

Comment: I upvoted because you suggested using maths to come up with a closed-form solution (constant time!) instead of calculating the sum by brute force. I'm not necessarily convinced that your solution is correct, but this is at least the correct mindset for attacking this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can calculate the value.

You compute the value iterratively for each number of digits in the binary representation of the upper limit. For each number of digits compute separately the sum of the degrees 1 to 4 of the numbers with even number of ones and of the numbers with odd number of ones in their binary representation. Having these values you should be able to compute the values for n+1 where n is the number of the digits in the binary representation.

Here are some observations on how to do that: If you have the sum of the k-th degrees of numbers with even number of ones, then multiply this by 2^k and you will get the sum of these numbers doubled. These numbers still will have even number of ones. In fact each number with n digits that has even number of ones is either doubled number with n-1 digits that has even number of ones, or is x * 2 + 1 where x is a number with odd number of ones and has n -1 digits. So the sum of the k-th degrees of the numbers that have even number of ones in their binary representation and have n digits is `Se(n,k) = 2^k * Se(n-1, k) + Sum(a : number with odd number of ones and n-1 digits){(2*a + 1)^k}`. Here I use Se to denote the sum of the numbers with even number of ones. Now the interesting part is the second summand. It can be calculated using the binomial formula:

(2*a + 1)^k = 2^k*a*k + combination(1,k)*(2*a)^(k-1) + ... 1 And so after regrouping you have:
`Sum(a : number with odd number of ones and n digits){(2*a + 1)^k} = 2^k*So(n-1,k) + combination(1, k) * 2^(k-1)*So(n-1,k) + combination(2, k) * 2^(k-2)*So(n-1,k) + ...`

Now if you assume you have the So(sum of numbers with odd number of ones in their binary representation) calculated for n-1 you can also calculate this sum.

You have to write similar formula for So(n,k):

So(n,k) = 2^k*(So(n-1, k)) + Sum(a : number with EVEN number of ones and n-1 digits){(2*a + 1)^k

Keep in mind you have to compute this values for k = 1, ... 4 so that you can use them for the next iteration. Only one note - for So(n, 1) you have So(n, 1) = So(n-1,1)*2 + Se(n-1,1)*2 + 1, similarly Se(n, 1) = Se(n-1, 1) * 2 + So(n-1, 1).

Using these formulas you should be able to compute the value you need quite fast. You need to sum Se(1,4) + Se(2,4) + ... Se(64, 4). The algorithm will work for values quite higher then the given constraints. Please note that the value you are searching for will not fit in any "regular" integer type. You will need to use some kind of BigInteger implementation.

Hope this answers your question.